# Apply complex arithmetic formulas to all fields in a table SQL

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I got a problem on this request:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ApNumber=0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ApNumber=1 THEN 100 
        WHEN ApNumber=2 THEN 250 
        WHEN ApNumber=3 THEN 500 
        WHEN ApNumber=4 THEN 750 
        WHEN ApNumber<=5 THEN 1000 END AS ApPoint,

    FactionInfo.FactionUUID


FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(isAP) AS ApNumber
        FROM ClaimInfo 
        WHERE FactionOwnerUUID =FactionInfo.FactionUUID
    )f0,

    FactionInfo
```

The problem is that

```
FactionInfo.FactionUUID
```

in  `WHERE FactionOwnerUUID =FactionInfo.FactionUUID`

produce the unknow column error.

The problem is that I want to perform all the calculations located in the select for all the lines located in the FactionInfo.
Advices ?

The final request should give me:

```
FactionUUID - ApPoint
----------------------
FactionUUIDName 250
FactionUUIDOtherName 750
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(isAP) = 0 THEN 0 -- this will never happen
             WHEN COUNT(isAP) = 1 THEN 100 
             WHEN COUNT(isAP) = 2 THEN 250 
             WHEN COUNT(isAP) = 3 THEN 500 
             WHEN COUNT(isAP) = 4 THEN 750 
             ELSE 1000
        END) AS ApPoint,
       ci.FactionOwnerUUID
FROM ClaimInfo ci
GROUP BY ci.FactionOwnerUUID;
```

Comment: The problem is that i want to add 
"WHERE isAP = true"

But i want that the request return a row event if no result as been finded